# Omnet++, NED file, Can I access display parameters for each node created?

Tags: syntax, omnet++

i simply want to position the nodes every time its created here in both loops
can anyone help me with the syntax?

```
network Network
{
   parameters:
    int noOfSources = default(2);
    int noOfSinks = default(2);
    double field_x;
    double field_y;
    //int noOfConnections;
submodules:
    source[noOfSources]: Source;
    sink[noOfSinks]: Sink;
    operator: Operator;
connections:
    for i=0..noOfSources-1 {
        source[i].gate <--> Link <--> operator.gate++;
    }
    for i=0..noOfSinks-1 {
        sink[i].gate <--> Link <--> operator.gate++;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can position the nodes in the NED iteration, but you can arrange the module vectors in rows/columns/rings/matrices using the @display property (display string).
Take a look at this section of the manual: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:display-strings:module-and-connection-display-strings

For example this:

```
source[noOfSources]: Source @display("p=50,40,r,25");
```

Will position the Sources in a row, with the first one at 50:40 and with a spacing of 25.

You can also move them around from C++, similarly using their cDisplayString objects (just like the mobility models of component libraries like INET do) but that is a lot less convenient.

Comment: Great! Now, I see your StackOverflow account is quite new, so you might not be familiar with this function just yet, but if you could consider marking my answer as "accepted" using the green check mark, so we can focus on "unanswered" questions, that would be awesome!
(Disclaimer: It also increases my "repetition".)